# Invalid payment_intent

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, stripe-payments, payment

I am following this tutorial here:

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/web#passing-to-client

At step four, I am calling

```
this.stripe.handleCardPayment(secret.secret,this.card,{
          payment_method_data: {
            billing_details: {name: this.cardholderName}
        }})
        .then(result => {
          if (result.error) {
            var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
            errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
            console.log("error")
          } else {
            console.log(result);
          }
        });
```

I get this Error: "No such payment_intent: pi_xxxxxxxxx..."

Can somebody help me please, I am working on this problem for hours now.

Comment: when do you get this error? when you're taking which action?

Comment: When I click the submit-button, after I entered my creditCardDetails, I call the function above, and the result.error.message is the mentioned error

Comment: what is the status code when you inspect the page?

Comment: No status code, just the console log output "error"